# AlertDialog and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-adapter, android-context

I have an Adapter which extend `ArrayAdapter`. With this adapter class I manage a `ListView` inside MainActivity.
I also have some buttons inside each row of the list and when I click on a button I want an `AlertDialog` to be shown. In doing so, I got an error about `Theme`.
I read about changing theme inside my manifest, but it does not work even if I change.

```
holder.delete=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn_item);
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                dialog.setTitle("Deleting...");
                dialog.setMessage("You are deleting DEFINITELY <" + db.getAllRecipes().get(position).getRec_name() + ">. Are you sure to continue?");
                dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        db.deleteRecipe(db.getAllRecipes().get(position));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "deleted " + db.getAllRecipes().get(position).getRec_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                dialog.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

I have the holder inside the getView method. My first code lines are:

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
DatabaseHelper db;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
PopupWindow popUpWndw;


List list= new ArrayList();
public RecipeAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
   this.context = context;
   db=new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: try change `AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());` to `AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`;

Comment: It seems you're mixing Support Library classes with "standard" one. Check that your Activity and dialogs have a match.

Comment: Can you please show us your `AndroidManifest.xml`, `style.xml` & error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: I passed context instead of getContext(), but the error message still remain the same

Comment: also I added in the manifest android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"...but it's the same...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

pass your `mainactivity` `context` to your custom adaptor  and use that `context` to create your `alertdialog`

```
 yourAdaptor(this); // this is mainactivity context
```

YourAdaptor

```
private Context mContext;

    public yourAdaptor(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext );
```

**Update ::**

*just pass your global context instance of adaptor.*

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: I see that he already pass the context to the `Adapter`.( `private Context context;`)

Comment: you are right  @PhanVănLinh. ohk so he have to use that context only .

Answer (score 0):

Use below theme for this activity in your menifest file

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the context to the adapter class through its constructor and it is saved in the variable "context".So use context instead of getcontext(). It worked for me.I think this will help you.

```
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Deleting...");
            dialog.setMessage("You are deleting DEFINITELY <" + db.getAllRecipes().get(position).getRec_name() + ">. Are you sure to continue?");
            dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    db.deleteRecipe(db.getAllRecipes().get(position));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "deleted " + db.getAllRecipes().get(position).getRec_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            dialog.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

change your style.xml with below code :-

**values**

"styles.xml"

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.package name.your activity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 </activity>
```